# Finding the determinant of this matrix B, using the determinant of Matrix A.

Tags: matrices, determinant

We are provided with a matrix and it's corresponding determine:

This Matrix, let's call it A, has a determinant of 4.

\begin{bmatrix}
    a    & b  & c \\
    d    & e  & f \\  
    g    & h  & i \\
\end{bmatrix}

We want to find the determinant of this Matrix, B,  using A.

\begin{bmatrix}
    2c    & b  & a \\
    2f    & e  & d \\  
    2i     & h  & g \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now I recognize that B is actually Matrix A, except Column 1 and 3 are swapped and Column 1 in B is multiplied by 2. However, I'm not sure how we can use this
information to find it's determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can transform the two column operations into a single matrix product:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    2c    & b  & a \\
    2f    & e  & d \\  
    2i     & h  & g
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    a    & b  & c \\
    d    & e  & f \\  
    g    & h  & i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0    & 0 & 1 \\
    0    & 1  & 0 \\  
    2    & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then it suffices to take the determinants on both sides: you will obtain $4 \times (-2)=-8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the determinant of a matrix is an [alternating multilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form) of the columns.

( also see: [Defining the determinant of linear transformations as multilinear alternating form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/defining-the-determinant-of-linear-transformations-as-multilinear-alternating-fo))